# VBA InStr() Not working the way I thought it would

Tags: excel, vba

I have a quick question:

```
For i = 0 to 8 Step 1
    If InStr(cell.Text, Str(i)) <> 0 Then
        'Do stuff
    End  If
Next i
```

Now, using msgbox(cell.text) i've been able to determine my string is "0N"
And Str(i) is "0". The way I understand InStr() is that it returns a integer for the position of what you are looking for. If it doesnt contain what you are looking for it returns 0. Why does this not work?

Comment: Get rid of `Str` and use the proper typecast `CStr`.

Comment: so what's the result of `MsgBox Left(cell.Text) = "0"` ?

Comment: Thank you for editing my question to more appropriate. I was more than a little frusterated at the moment @DavidZemens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the `InStr` function is correct. Your assumption about the `Str` function, however, is incorrect :)

The [`Str` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6a1sx7(v=vs.90).aspx) adds a leading space if there is no sign, so you are comparing a single character to *two* characters: `" 0"` which will always be false.

> When numbers are converted to strings, a leading space is always reserved for the sign of Number. If Number is positive, the returned string contains a leading space, and the plus sign is implied.

Use `Cstr(i)` to avoid this,

```
If InStr(cell.Text, CStr(i)) <> 0 Then
```

or nest your `Str` function within a `Trim`:

```
If InStr(cell.Text, Trim(Str(i))) <> 0 Then
```

Note also that `0 = "0"` in VBA, so you technically don't *need* to cast explicitly to string, though it's probably a good habit.

```
If Instr(cell.Text, i) <> 0 Then ' <-- this should also work
```